# How to show new version popup to force reload on web apps

Tags: javascript, html, angular, caching, web-applications

Basically our Angular apps usually cache js/html files, and this is a problem when we release new versions as some of the pages still use the old cached files and therefore cause an error. This is obviously easily fixed by force reload, but not all users are familiar with

So, I just want to show popups that i see in pages that show something like[image: reload popup]

Problem is I'm not sure what its called to even start researching about it.

And in case anyone is familiar with it, follow up question: do I need to track a frontend and backend version identification for this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can call a dedicated endpoint that returns the latest FE version. Then compare it with the running FE version (as e.g. explained here: https://dev.to/nightwolfdev/how-to-display-app-version-in-angular-2ge). The endpoint can be smart and also provide information whether the running FE version is compatible with the running BE version, and if not force reloading the latest FE version and/or display an appropriate message like Google does.

Answer (score 2):

**IMPORTANT** I don't check in production, but I imagine should be work

You can have in your assets folder a file called version.json

```
{
  version:2.0.0
}
```

And a provider in your main module

```
providers:[{provide:'VERSION',useValue:'2.0.0'}]
```

You can create a service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  noMatchVersion$ = this.httpClient
    .get('assets/version.json', {
      headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        Pragma: 'no-cache',
      },
    })
    .pipe(map((res: any) => res.version != this.version));
    
  constructor(
    @Inject('VERSION') private version: string,
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}
}
```

Now, when you subscribe to the dataService.noMatchVersion$ Observable you get true if not match, so you can e.g. in your main.app

```
<div *ngIf="dataService.noMatchVersion$|async">no match version</div>

constructor(public dataService:DataService){}
```

The only you need remember change the version.json and the value in your provider

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3qru3e?file=src%2Fmain.ts,angular.json,src%2Fdata.service.ts,src%2Fassets%2Fversion.json)

**Update** Really I don't know how force reload. Again I imagine we can add a new method to our service

```
  refresh()
  {
    this.httpClient
    .get(window.location.href, {
      responseType: 'text',
      headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        Pragma: 'no-cache',
      },
    }).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      window.location.reload()
    })
  }
```

So, our main can be like

```
<div *ngIf="dataService.noMatchVersion$|async"><p>A new version is available</p>
<button (click)="refresh()">Refresh</button>
</div>

  refresh()
  {
    this.dataService.refresh()
  }
```

Comment: Both are in angular, wouldnt that just cause the service to be cached hence always cause both versions to match? But assuming they do work, after seeing versions dont match, how'd I force reload the page? Sorry im not familiar with how js/html are cached in browsers especially angular apps. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I imagine you can do using pure javascript adding a querystring to the url,e.g.: `const date=new Date();window.location="your-url?"+date.getTime()" (again, please check in production and apologies in advance if it doesn't work)

Comment: @JordinVell, I update the answer. I'm not pretty sure that if you make an httpClient.get over the url really refresh the index